# Correct invalidation path for CloudFront object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

I am trying to figure out the correct path for an object to invalidate on CloudFront distribution.

CloudFront is configured with an alternate domain name of `*.example.com`

The tricky part is that I've setup a custom origin on EC2 that uses HAProxy to do some path rewriting.

So that the request to

`mysubdomain.example.com/icon.png`

is rewritten to

`s3.amazonaws.com/examplebucket/somedirectory/mysubdomain/icon.png`

and the result is then returned to CloudFront. (So, both the Path and the Host are being rewritten)

Now, I have trouble figuring out the correct path for this object when sending an invalidation request. (I don't want to use versioning, because I need the filename to remain the same)

I've tried with the following configuration, but it doesn't seem to be working. The invalidation is created and processed, but with no effect.

```
const invalidationParams = {
  DistributionId: 'MY_DISTRIBUTION_ID',
  InvalidationBatch: {
    CallerReference: 'SOME_RANDOM_STRING',
    Paths: {
      Quantity: 1,
      Items: [
        '/somedirectory/mysubdomain/icon.png'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Since only PATH is specified, which is relative to the distribution, and no way to specify the full URL in the invalidation configuration, does it make it impossible to invalidate the object in this configuration?

Comment: Just use this path "/somedirectory/mysubdomain/" it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFront invalidations consider *every* object matching the path specification, as requested by the browser.  To invalidate `http://example.com/cat.jpg` you specify one of the following:

```
cat.jpg
/cat.jpg
```

The leading slash is optional, but implied if absent.

Paths are the only values accepted for invalidation requests.

For each edge location, every copy of an object matching that path -- regardless of the alternate domain name or other attributes associated with in it -- will be evicted.

Note that "every copy of an object matching that path" may be confusing to some, since the assumption might be that only one copy would match a given path, but this is not correct.  CloudFront caches different copies of the "same" object, depending on which request parameters are forwarded to the origin.  If the query string, a cookie, whitelisted headers, etc., are forwarded, then many copies of the "same" object will be cached, because caching requires that the cache assume the response will vary if any if the forwarded request parameters vary.  This is why so little forwarded by default -- it helps your hit rate because it reduces the likelihood of any given request seeming "unique" to the cache logic.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer, but it's still not working. I tried with '/mysubdomain/icon.png' path, but after invalidation is completed the old file is still loading in the browser (I cleared the browser cache).

Comment: I tried to make this part clear by using the phrase *the path specification, as requested by the browser*.  Use the request path from the front-end, not the rewritten (prepended) back-end path.  Just specify `/icon.png` if the browser gets the object using `GET /icon.png HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: But in that case it would invalidate all of the `icon.png` files in the distribution, not the one under the path I need, wouldn't it? So there is not way to invalidate just the one I need if it is under a "back-end" path?

Comment: It will invalidate anything called icon.png at the root of any of the sites, when multiple sites pass through the same distribution.  No problem, though, as soon as any of the other files (the ones you didn't want to evict) are requested again, they'll just be re-fetched.  CloudFront is a cache, after all, so its contents are ephemeral by definition and can be spontaneously evicted at any time, anyway. Also, an object is not "either cached or not cached" at any given time: each of the 50+ edge locations has an independent cache, only containing objects requested through that particular edge.

Comment: And, no, there is not a way to do a more specific eviction than by request path patterns.

Comment: Not a big problem, of course, but if all of the files with that name will be invalidated it might become a problem when I have hundreds or more sites in my distribution, since only 1000 path invalidations are free in a month. It seems the only other solution for me would be to use unique filenames for each website.

Comment: or, actually it doesn't matter because it's 1000 paths per month not 1000 objects, right? So, it doesn't make a difference anyway.

Comment: Right.  Each *path* counts towards the 1,000 free invalidations allowed per month, no matter how many objects that path actually matches.  So `images/cat.jpg`, `images/*.jpg`, `images/*`, or even `*`   (to invalidate everything in the entire distribution) is just counted as 1 invalidation path.  (Also remember that the 1,000 free invalidation path limit is across all your CloudFront distributions in an account, not for each distribution.)