# Why CloudFront returns a different image depending on the origin header?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

This one has kept me puzzled for a while:
I'm hosting images on s3 and serving them via Cloudfront.
I wanted to replace an existing image, so I uploaded it to s3 using the same name, invalidated the cache on Cloudfront, and cleared my local browser's cache.

To my surprise, the old image was still loading. But the crazy thing is that the same URL would return different images according to the headers used.

This request will return the old image:
[image]

If I included the origin header it would return the old image, if I didn't use that header it would return the new image.

[image]

Note how the Remote Adresses are different too:

[2600:9000:2026:**e200**:b:4a3b:3600:93a1]:443 vs
[2600:9000:2026:**600**:b:4a3b:3600:93a1]:443

It's worth pointing out that the uploaded s3 images have the following metadata:

```
Cache-Control public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000
```

And that I invalidated Cloudfront's cache according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38029854/1519464) as follows

[image]

**How can I make sure it consistently returns the new image?**